# Using 2 external monitors with a docking station connected to a laptop

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, resolution, docking-station

I work from a mobile office (office setup in my RV). I have an ASUS laptop and 2 external LED monitors (Samsung & Acer). I have been trying to use the 2 monitors connected to my laptop via an HDMI for one and a VGA for the other. Due to the limited space, I do NOT want to use the monitor that is part of my laptop when connected to the external monitors.

As somebody may have guessed, I have a problem with resolution when I mirror my laptop monitor (1366 x 768) to my external monitor (1920 x 1080). It was suggested that I purchase a docking station, which I have.
What I cannot figure out is how to get the settings correct for the scenario I would like to run. I have my laptop setup already to be able to close the lid and the computer does not shut off. However, the resolution on the monitor (display 2) that I have selected for the mirroring for my laptop (display 1) is still off. It is still trying to display the 1366x768 instead of 1920x1080. The 2nd LED monitor (display 3), which is the extended to display, looks great. When I tried to setup all 3 as separate monitors, upon closing the lid of the laptop so I can see both of the external monitors, I cannot see any of the items on my desktop (I can only see them if I open the laptop lid and look at that monitor). Only the taskbar appears on the external monitors (display 2 & 3).

Can somebody please explain how I can mirror the laptop screen to one of the external LED monitors but have the external LED monitor display with the correct 1920x1080 resolution?

I end up with a headache and VERY tired eyes daily and I'm sure it's my eyes trying to adjust from the resolution on the one monitor where everything is correctly sized and then glancing to the other mirrored monitor where everything is too large.

My OS is Windows 10.

Help is greatly appreciated!